# Getting the recurrence relation for Legendre polynomials by Leibnitz rule

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives, recurrence-relations, legendre-polynomials

Exercise:

For each natural number $n$ define
$$\phi_n(x)=\frac{d^n}{d x^n}\left(x^2-1\right)^n$$
Derive the formulas
$$\phi_{n+1}^{\prime}(x)=2(n+1) x \phi_n^{\prime}(x)+2(n+1)^2 \phi_n(x)$$
$$\phi_{n+1}^{\prime}(x)=\left(\left(x^2-1\right) \phi_n^{\prime}(x)\right)^{\prime}+2(n+1) x \phi_n^{\prime}(x)+(n+1)(n+2) \phi_n(x)$$
Hint. Attack the expressions
$$\frac{d^{n+2}}{d x^{n+2}}\left(x^2-1\right)^{n+1} \space\space   \frac{d^{n+1}}{d x^{n+1}}\left(x^2-1\right)^{n+1}$$

Mt attempt:
$$\frac{d^{n+2}}{d x^{n+2}}\left(x^2-1\right)^{n+1}=\sum_{k=0}^{n+2}\binom{n+2}{k} \frac{d^{k}}{d x^{k}}\left(x^2-1\right) \frac{d^{n+2-k}}{d x^{n+2-k}}\left(x^2-1\right)^{n}$$
Obviously survives only $k=0,1,2$ - th terms
$$\frac{d^{n+2}}{d x^{n+2}}\left(x^2-1\right)^{n+1}=(x^2-1)\frac{d^{n+2}}{d x^{n+2}}\left(x^2-1\right)^{n}+2x(n+2)\frac{d^{n+1}}{d x^{n+1}}\left(x^2-1\right)^{n}+(n+2)(n+1)\frac{d^{n+1}}{d x^{n+1}}\left(x^2-1\right)^{n}$$
$$\phi_{n+1}^{\prime}(x)=(x^2-1)\phi_n^{\prime\prime}(x)+2(n+2) x \phi_n^{\prime}(x)+(n+1)(n+2) \phi_n(x)$$
$$\phi_{n+1}^{\prime}(x)=\left(\left(x^2-1\right) \phi_n^{\prime}(x)\right)^{\prime}+2(n+1) x \phi_n^{\prime}(x)+(n+1)(n+2) \phi_n(x)$$
I succeeded to get the second formula but coludn't find the first formula.

Could anybody help me, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To simplify notation, I write $\delta_n$ instead of $\frac{d^n}{dx^n}$ ; thus
$\phi_n(x)=\delta_n((x^2-1)^n)$. We then have

$$
\begin{array}{lcl}
\phi_{n+1}(x) &=& \delta_{n+1} ((x^2-1)^{n+1}) \\
 &=& \delta_{n+1} ((x^2-1)(x^2-1)^{n}) \\
 &=& \delta_{n} (2x(x^2-1)^{n}+(x^2-1)2nx(x^2-1)^{n-1}) \\
 &=& \delta_{n} (2x(x^2-1)^{n}+2nx(x^2-1)^{n}) \\
 &=& 2(n+1)\delta_{n} (x(x^2-1)^{n}) \\
\end{array}
$$

It follows that

$$
\begin{array}{lcl}
\phi'_{n+1}(x) &=& 2(n+1)\delta_{n+1} (x(x^2-1)^{n}) \\
 &=& 2(n+1)\sum_{j=0}^{n+1} \binom{n+1}{j} \delta_{j} (x) \delta_{(n+1)-j} ((x^2-1)^{n}) \\
 &=& 2(n+1)\sum_{j=0}^{1} \binom{n+1}{j} \delta_{j} (x) \delta_{(n+1)-j} ((x^2-1)^{n}) \\
 &=& 2(n+1)\bigg(x\delta_{n+1} ((x^2-1)^{n})+(n+1)\delta_{n} ((x^2-1)^{n})\bigg) \\
 &=& 2(n+1)\bigg(x\phi'_{n}(x)+(n+1)\phi_n(x)\bigg) \\
\end{array}
$$
which proves the first formula.

Comment: Very Nice thank you Sir

Comment: In the last two lines the character $x$ was missed. I could't edit

Comment: @emilagazade Fixed, thanks.